# Trying to access element of an array returns TypeError: data.list is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```
function WeatherCard({day, data}) {
    console.log(data.list) // Logs an Array of objects
    console.log(data.list instanceof Array) // Outputs true
    console.log(data.list[0]) // TypeError: data.list is not defined
    return (
        <Card className="weather-card" title={"Title"} bordered={false} style={{ width: 300 }}>
            <p>Card content</p>
            <p>Card content</p>
            <p>Card content</p>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

I am trying to get an element of data.list but it gives me a TypeError, while when I log data.list it returns an array. At first it logs an undefined, which I think has to do with the useEffect, but then it logs the array. Does anyone know why it would be giving me an error?

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('US');
  const [state, setState] = useState('Illinois');
  const [city, setCity] = useState('Chicago');

  useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},${state}${country}&appid=${API_key}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setData(data);
        })
  }, [city, state, country]);
```

Here is the WeatherCard being used in the return statement:

```
<div className="site-card-wrapper">
  <Row gutter={18}>
    <Col span={4.5}>
      <WeatherCard day='1' data={data}></WeatherCard>
    </Col>
    <Col span={4.5}>
      <WeatherCard day='2' data={data}></WeatherCard>
    </Col>
    <Col span={4.5}>
      <WeatherCard day='3' data={data}></WeatherCard>
    </Col>
    <Col span={4.5}>
      <WeatherCard day='4' data={data}></WeatherCard>
    </Col>
    <Col span={4.5}>
      <WeatherCard day='5' data={data}></WeatherCard>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show where you're calling `WeatherCard` in relation to your component in the 2nd code?

Comment: Did you debug to check if at all steps data.list was as expected and that the console didn't log something else?

Comment: I guess you should add an if statement to prevent any future errors and show a loading state to the user instead (if the data is not ready yet show loading). This should give more info about what's happening in your code and where the problem is located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `WeatherCard` before the data has been populated, so the `data={data}` does not contain the values that `WeatherCard` (sounds like it) requires to render.

You could use conditional rendering instead, so that `WeatherCard` doesn't get called until you actually have the data to populate `WeatherCard`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
// ...
return !data ? null : (
  <div className="site-card-wrapper">
    <Row gutter={18}>
      <Col span={4.5}>
        <WeatherCard day='1' data={data}></WeatherCard>
      </Col>
      <Col span={4.5}>
        <WeatherCard day='2' data={data}></WeatherCard>
      </Col>
      <Col span={4.5}>
        <WeatherCard day='3' data={data}></WeatherCard>
      </Col>
      <Col span={4.5}>
        <WeatherCard day='4' data={data}></WeatherCard>
      </Col>
      <Col span={4.5}>
        <WeatherCard day='5' data={data}></WeatherCard>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </div>
);
```